# invalid use of non-static member function in stream_descriptor::async_wait

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Debian Linux, Boost 1.67.
Taking the example from boost on coding boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::async_wait and placing in a class I get "invalid use of non-static member function" on the wait_handler in the async_wait line.

Boost Example

```
void wait_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Wait succeeded.
  }
}

...

boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor descriptor(io_context);
...
descriptor.async_wait(
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read,
    wait_handler);
```

Converted to

```
void EHandler::wait_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Wait succeeded.
  }
}


void EHandler::StartRead()
{
  ...
  boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor descriptor(io_context);

  descriptor.async_wait(boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read, wait_handler);
}
```

Tried:

```
... wait_handler, this);
... EHandler::wait_handler);
... &EHandler::wait_handler);
... EHandler::wait_handler, this);
... &EHandler::wait_handler, this);
... boost::bind() with each of the above options
```

Even tried adding _1) to each.
What am I overlooking?

Since this routine will be called from up to 8 threads it cannot be declared static, which is a suggestion on just the error message cure.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested fully yet, this is just getting past the compiler error.

descriptor.async_wait(boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read, boost::bind(&EHandler::wait_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));